# group bar, from 3rd onwards coming separately

Tags: d3.js

Here is my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/x8rax/9/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>




  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    .chart rect {
  fill:#98abc5 ;

}

.chart2 rect {
  fill:#8a89a6 ;

}

.chart3 rect {
  fill:#7b6888 ;

}

.chart4 rect {
  fill:#6b486b ;

}

.chart5 rect {
  fill:#a05d56 ;

}

.chart6 rect {
  fill:#d0743c ;

}

.chart7 rect {
  fill:#ff8c00 ;

}



.chart {
  position: absolute;   
}



.chart text {
  fill: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
var data = [4, 8, 15, 78, 100, 90];
var width = 420,
    barHeight = 80;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, width]);


var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", barHeight * data.length);


var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight +")"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("height", barHeight - 70);




var data = [10, 30, 20, 1000, 9, 500];


var width = 420,
    barHeight = 80;

var chart = d3.select(".chart2")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", barHeight * data.length);


var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + (i * barHeight + barHeight - 70 )  +")"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("height", barHeight - 70);

var data = [500, 100, 60, 20, 1000, 9];

var width = 420,
    barHeight = 80;

var chart = d3.select(".chart3")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", barHeight * data.length);


var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + (i * barHeight + barHeight - 60 )  +")"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("height", barHeight - 70);



}//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <svg class="chart"></svg>
<svg class = "chart2"></svg>
<svg class = "chart3"></svg>
<svg class = "chart4"></svg>
<svg class = "chart5"></svg>
<svg class = "chart6"></svg>
<svg class = "chart7"></svg>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, 3rd onwards it's coming separately. I want to create the group bar chart with 7 different bars. I am right now stuck in 3rd.

Comment: Please reduce the code to the necessary party and invest some time writing a detailed description of the problem.

Comment: sorry I don't know how to reduce it. I am very new to Ui scripting.

Answer (score 1):

It is coming separately because the svg tags with classes chart2 onwards are not positioned absolutely.
It works if you add a css rule as follows:

```
.chart2, .chart3, .chart4, .chart5, .chart6, .chart7{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Please note however, that your current approach is not generic and you end up needing to create specific svg tags and repeating the bar chart creation code.

Please refer the grouped bar example at: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051